# Ordenando valores por ponteiros

Tags: c, funções, algoritmo, ponteiro, classificação

Boas, estava fazendo um exercicio que pedia para ler 3 numeros reais, ordena-los e mostrar de modo ordenado. Pensei que fazendo uma função que usa-se ponteiros seria uma boa ideia, mas o programa sempre retorna os valor sem ordem. Testei com "10.0 7.0 20.0", "10.0 20.0 7.0".

Queria saber se errei no uso dos ponteiros ou meu erro está na lógica.

Segue o código:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void _sort (float *x, float *y, float *z);
int main (){
    void _sort (float *x, float *y, float *z);
    float a, b, c;
    scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);

    _sort (&a, &b, &c);

    printf("%.1f \n%.1f \n%.1f", a, b, c);
}
void _sort (float* x, float* y, float* z){
    float temp;
    if (x < y){
        temp = *x;
        *x = *y;
        *y = temp;
    }
    if (y < z){
        temp = *y;
        *y = *z;
        *z = temp;
    }
    if ((x < y) && (y < z))
        _sort (x, y, z);
}
```

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Queria saber se errei no uso dos ponteiros ou meu erro está na lógica".

Certamente no uso dos ponteiros, ou no não-uso nas comparações. E a lógica ainda não entendi. Pode estar até certo mas é incrivelmente complicado.

E errou ao não testar o retorno de `scanf()`. Não há propósito em seguir se não leu os 3 valores.

Trata-se apenas de classificar 3 elementos. Isso envolve 3 comparações. Então não entendo porque usar recursão ao invés de escrever apenas isso

#### exemplo

```
void _sort (float* x, float* y, float* z)
{
    float temp;
    if( *x > *y )
    {
        temp = *x;
        *x = *y;
        *y = temp;
    };
    if( *y > *z )
    {
        temp = *y;
        *y = *z;
        *z = temp;
    };
    if( *x > *y )
    {
        temp = *x;
        *x = *y;
        *y = temp;
    };
    return;
};  // _sort()
```

eu acho que já serviria. O *bubble sort* sem loop. Duas comparações deixam o maior valor em z. Uma comparação depois leva o menor para x. E retorna.

```
PS C:\src\ifdef> gcc -o tsort3 -Wall -std=c17 tsort3.c
PS C:\src\ifdef> ./tsort3
PS C:\src\ifdef> ./tsort3    
Entre com 3 valores [numeros reais] : 1 2 3
Em ordem crescente: 1.0 2.0 3.0
PS C:\src\ifdef> ./tsort3
Entre com 3 valores [numeros reais] : 3 2 1
Em ordem crescente: 1.0 2.0 3.0
PS C:\src\ifdef> ./tsort3
Entre com 3 valores [numeros reais] : 1 3 2
Em ordem crescente: 1.0 2.0 3.0
PS C:\src\ifdef> ./tsort3
Entre com 3 valores [numeros reais] : -3.1 -3.22 -3.333
Em ordem crescente: -3.3 -3.2 -3.1
PS C:\src\ifdef>
```

é a saída desse programa

```
#include<stdio.h>

void _sort (float*,float*,float*);

int main (void)
{
    void _sort (float *x, float *y, float *z);
    float a, b, c;
    printf("Entre com 3 valores [numeros reais] : ");
    int res = scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);
    if (res != 3) return -1; 
    _sort (&a, &b, &c);
    printf("Em ordem crescente: %.1f %.1f %.1f", a, b, c);
    return 0;
};

void _sort (float* x, float* y, float* z)
{
    float temp;
    if( *x > *y )
    {
        temp = *x;
        *x = *y;
        *y = temp;
    };
    if( *y > *z )
    {
        temp = *y;
        *y = *z;
        *z = temp;
    };
    if( *x > *y )
    {
        temp = *x;
        *x = *y;
        *y = temp;
    };
    return;
};  // _sort()
```

> Entendi, obrigado. Nunca tinha pensado em testar o retorno do scanf, mas parece uma excelente prática. Só uma curiosidade, o return -1; serve para retornar para algum ponto?

- se usar scanf() teste o retorno. Simples assim. É muito ingênuo deixar o programa seguir sem saber se leu o que pretendia. E `scanf()` não foi escrita para isso que está fazendo: ler do teclado. `scanf()` foi escrita para ler entrada formatada. Veja o nome: **scanf f**ormatted input. O teclado é *free-form*: 105 teclas de liberdade, ou mais.
- retornar -1, ou qualquer coisa diferente serve para você saber por onde foi que seu programa saiu, quando tem um programa simples e não quer ficar tratando as possíveis 400 condições de erro com 400 mensagens bonitinhas. Você vai retornando -1, -2, -3, 4000, 5000, qualquer coisa. E quando o programa termina você vai lá e vê qual o código de retorno e sabe por onde ele saiu. Preguiça apenas.

> "Por mais que tenha tentado colocar mais ou menos que 3 valores, o
> sistema ou ficava em pronto esperando os valores restantes ou apenas
> computava os 3 primeiro"

talvez o mais que usou não seja suficiente. :) com 3 especificadores `scanf()` pode retornar -1, 0, 1, 2 ou 3. -1 vai indicar um erro e vai ser difícil com o teclado. Se passar mais de 3 valores na entrada os restantes vão claro ficar no buffer de entrada à disposição do programa.  NUNCA vai retornar mais que o número de especificadores porque não faria sentido.

scanf() tem uma missão. No programa

```
int res = scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);
```

Então há 3 `%f` e a função vai consumir a entrada até ler isso. Só que tem regras. Espaços, TABS e newlines serão consumidos silenciosamente. Ao ler o que foi pedido a função retorna. Não é possível retornar mais do que 3.

Considere esse código

```
    printf("Entre com 3 valores [numeros reais] : ");
    int res = scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);
    if (res != 3)
    {
        switch(res)
        {
            case  1: return -1;
            case  2: return -2;
            case  0: return -3;
            default:
                return -4; // so pode ser -1
        }   // switch()
    };  // if()
```

Então:

- se o programa não ler nadinha vai retornar -3
- se ler um valor retorna -1
- se ler dois valores retorna  -2
- se der erro `scanf()` retorna -1 e o `switch()` vai retornar -4. quando dá erro você pode testar o valor de `errorno` no programa e usar `perror()` para mostrar a razão do erro, num programa sério. Aqui a única razão provável de erro é fim de arquivo, o que acontece se você teclar control-Z na leitura.

De todo modo no Mac/Linux você testa $? depois de rodar o programa e tem o código de erro.

No Windows é mais chato: na console você testa %ERRORLEVEL% mas no Terminal do Windows ou no PowerShell é diferente... No PS você roda como no Linux echo $?
mas vem True se o último programa terminou OK e False se deu erro. Dar erro quer dizer não retornar zero. Em C tem a constante `EXIT_SUCCESS` e a irmã `EXIT_FAILURE` justamente reservadas para isso. É uma convenção silenciosa.

E se deu erro você pode ver em $LASTEXITCODE qual foi o valor de retorno. Não me culpe. Também odiei isso.

#### uma _sort() recursiva

Algoritmos de sort como o MergeSort o HeapSort e o QuickSort tem mais sentido em serem implementados via recursão. De todo modo

```
 void _sortR (float* x, float* y, float* z)
{
    float temp;
    if( *x > *y )
    {
        temp = *x;
        *x = *y;
        *y = temp;
        _sortR( x,y,z );
    };
    if( *y > *z )
    {
        temp = *y;
        *y = *z;
        *z = temp;
        _sortR( x,y,z );
    };
    if( *x > *y )
    {
        temp = *x;
        *x = *y;
        *y = temp;
        _sortR( x,y,z );
    };
    return;
};  // _sort()
```

Essa versão de _sort() é recursiva, se queria ver um exemplo.

#### um teste de scanf() no windows

```
C:\src\ifdef>gcc -o tsort3 -Wall -std=c17 tsort3.c

C:\src\ifdef>tsort3
Entre com 3 valores [numeros reais] : 1 2 3
Em ordem crescente: 1.0 2.0 3.0
C:\src\ifdef>tsort3
Entre com 3 valores [numeros reais] : 3 2 1
Em ordem crescente: 1.0 2.0 3.0
C:\src\ifdef>tsort3
Entre com 3 valores [numeros reais] : ^Z

C:\src\ifdef>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
-4

C:\src\ifdef>tsort3
Entre com 3 valores [numeros reais] : 1x

C:\src\ifdef>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
-1

C:\src\ifdef>tsort3
Entre com 3 valores [numeros reais] : 1 2asda

C:\src\ifdef>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
-2

C:\src\ifdef>tsort3
Entre com 3 valores [numeros reais] : fim

C:\src\ifdef>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
-3

C:\src\ifdef>
```

Comment: Vlw, não sei o que dizer quanto a lógica estar complicada, rascunhei primeiro no papel e me pareceu aceitavel. Quanto ao uso de ponteiro e recursão, usei para praticar, já que recursão é uma pedra no meu sapato. Entendi que o uso das três condicionais no '_sort', parece bem mais compreensível mesmo.

Comment: Teste o retorno de `scanf()`. Se quer usar recursão aqui entenda que recursão é apenas um loop mais lento e sem contexto. Então eis o que pode fazer: em _sort() continue chamando _sort até não fazer nenhuma troca. Se quiser um exemplo escreva e te mostro um. Mas recomendo você tentar... Pode usar a mesma função que te mostrei

Comment: Entendi, obrigado. Nunca tinha pensado em testar o retorno do scanf, mas parece uma excelente prática. Só uma curiosidade, o return -1; serve para retornar para algum ponto? Por mais que tenha tentado colocar mais ou menos que 3 valores, o sistema ou ficava em pronto esperando os valores restantes ou apenas computava os 3 primeiro.

Comment: retornar -1 é usado para você poder saber de onde o programa retornou quando dá erro. Em geral em programas assim de estudo simples não se trata todos os erros e dá mensagens explicando 300 condições que tem deveriam acontecer. Então você vai retornando -1, -2, -n. E na linha de comando você pode usar echo %ERRORLEVEL% no Windows ou echo $? no Mac/Linux e vai mostrar -1. -2, n. Assim você sabe onde o programa parou...

Comment: ok ok vou editar a resposta e explicar como funciona...

Answer (score 0):

O erro está nas duas coisas. O erro dos ponteiros está nos IFs, faltou usar o asterisco:

```
if (*x < *y)
if (*y < *z)
if(*x < *y) && (*y < *z)
```

O erro de lógica está na forma expressão da chamada recursiva. Dá uma olhadinha e se você não conseguir eu altero depois.

A lógica estava quase certa, mas no lugar do && vc deveria usar ||:

```
   if(*x < *y || *y < *z)
```

Comment: Opa, valeu mesmo. Não sei porque, mas pensava que podia comparar sem os asteriscos. Na parte da recursividade tinha tentado colacar '&x, &y, &z' ou colocar '*x, *y, *z' e tomava error de "incompatible type for argument", acho que faltava o "return", mas isso não retornou o que esperava, vou precisar estudar um pouco mais de recursividade.

Comment: poder pode, mas vai comparar o endereço dos ponteiros, não os valores

Comment: Quanto a recursividade, alterando o ultimo condiciona `if ((x < y) && (y < z)) {_sort (x, y, z);}` para ` if (*x < *y) {  _sort(x,y,z);}` o algoritmo funciona